# Remote access to EnterpriseDB PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, qgis, enterprisedb, bigsql, postgresql-bigsql

When I install PostgreSQL from BigSQL I can connect from QGIS on other PC to my local PostgreSQL Server (both PCs are on the same local network 192.168.100.0/24). But then I can't install PostGIS because it always says `$libdir/postgis-2-3` can't be found (even I copied that folder to libdir path).

When I install PostgreSQL from EnterpriseDB, I install PostGIS very easy. BUT, now I can't access my server remotely (from QGIS).

In both cases I added proper configs to `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` files (port, listen_address and allowed hosts). Then I restart my server but nothing.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Did you let postgres set environmet variable paths for lib files? It usually initiates during installation progress. Check the path from shell with path command

Comment: _I can't access my server remotely_: please describe that in terms of what happens

Comment: @CagCak Yes, I let postgres t set envs for all.

Comment: @DanielVérité It says to check if server is running on my IP and to check port. That's all set up, but QGIS is unable to see it.

Comment: Generally it means the remote server is not listening at the host/interface/port you're giving to QGIS. Incorrect `listen_addresses` is the first suspect.

Comment: @DanielVérité I set it as follows: '*'. Do I need to set up something in Firewall?